# cipherText = aes-ctr(key, iv+1, (plainText)); & authTag= aes-ctr(key, iv, aes-ecb(key, sha-1(cipherText+authData+key+iv))); is it secure?

Tags: aes, sha-1

Proposed Cipher suite (using **aes-ecb**):

```
cipherText = aes-ctr(key, ++iv, (plainText)); & authTag= aes-ctr(key, iv, aes-ecb(key, sha-1(cipherText+authData+key+iv)));
```

---

Security targets:

1. Encryption of the plainText.
2. Integrity of the cipherText & authData.
3. Authenticity of the cipherText & authData.

---

Used components and reason behind using them:

1. sha-1: For checking integrity of the cipherText & authData.
2. aes-ctr: Used for encryption of the plaintext & aes-ecb(sha1).
3. aes-ctr(**aes-ecb**(sha-1(***cipherText+authData+key+iv)))*:

   - sha-1 is encrypted with **aes-ecb** to create hurdle in finding out the key stream used by aes-ctr to encrypt `aes-ecb(sha1). Because even if the attacker get to know sha-1, sha-1's encrypted value could not be guessed.
   - sha-1 is used to encrypt the cipherText & authData along with **key + iv**: So that we can check integrity of cipherText & authData. `key + iv` is added to create hurdle for attackers to guess value of sha-1.

---

The challenge/question is to find out security level of this cipher suite.

This question is for **passionate & elite cryptanalysts**, which would help them or other (from their answers), to understand how use of a broken hash function determines overall security?

I hope that some people would find this as a interesting challenge.

---

*Please note that value of sha-1 is truncated to block size.(i.e, 128 bits)

This method is improved version derived from the method proposed in this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64834/aes-ctrkey-iv-sha-1plaintext-aes-ctrkey-iv-0128plaintext-aes-ctr).

Comment: [This conversation has been archived to chat. As NKaran doesn't have enough reputation to post in chat, please have any relevant discussions in the comments and once they're done, flag them and I'll archive them to chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87056/discussion-on-question-by-nkaran-ciphertext-aes-ctrkey-iv1-plaintext).

Answer (score 3):

> I was just trying to build a secure enough cipher suite using aes and
>   a sha-1 function

Your safest bet for this is to use AES-CTR and apply HMAC-SHA1 on the ciphertext. This should still be secure (because HMAC doesn't rely on collision resistance and mitigates length extensions). I.e. $$(c,\tau)=((\text{IV},\operatorname{AES-CTR}_{k,\text{IV}}(m)),\operatorname{HMAC-SHA1}_k(c))$$

> Proposed Cipher suite (using aes-ecb):

I'm *reasonably confident* that this hits at least around a 64-bit security level, but the construction is too complex and too non-standard for me to trust my ad-hoc evaluation. Of course 64-bit is much less than you can get from more standard modes like [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), [CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode) and [EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) which should be preferred.

---

Additional nodes on sub-constructions:

- [The encryption of the hash yields in itself a blocksize/2-bit secure MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3229/23623). The CTR application *could* mitigate structural attacks on SHA1 here.
- [$H(m\| k)$ (and variants) suffers from collision attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5725/23623). This *may* be (partially) mitigated by the subsequent encryption operations.
- [$H(k\| m)$ (and variants) suffers from length-extension attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1070/23623). This *may* be (partially) mitigated by the subsequent encryption operations.

Final conclusion:
**Do not use this for applications where security actually matters!**
When it doesn't matter and attackers will only invest a low amount of effort this has a chance of providing adequate security.

Comment: Well answered. This answer satisfies the need. But I am looking for an answer which can removes the "may be (partially)", and "ad-hoc evaluation" of this answer. Again thank you very much.